# 8GB of 10GB disk on GCP VM taken by google sdk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Hello I have a GCP VM which is out of disk space (a 10 GB disk). I am using `ncdu` to figure out where all the space is being used.

```
--- / ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.   4.3 GiB [##########] /snap
.   3.2 GiB [#######   ] /var
    2.1 GiB [####      ] /usr
.   1.7 GiB [###       ] /home
......
```

```
--- /snap ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         /..
    2.7 GiB [##########] /google-cloud-sdk
  624.5 MiB [##        ] /lxd
. 404.5 MiB [#         ] /core20
  356.8 MiB [#         ] /snapd
. 338.5 MiB [#         ] /core18
    4.0 KiB [          ] /bin
    4.0 KiB [          ]  README
```

It seems that 2.7GB is taken up by the `google-cloud-sdk`

and within /var/lib/snapd/snaps:

```
--- /var/lib/snapd/snaps ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         /..
  334.8 MiB [##########]  google-cloud-sdk_310.snap
  308.6 MiB [######### ]  google-cloud-sdk_308.snap
  279.5 MiB [########  ]  google-cloud-sdk_312.snap.partial
```

Are these snapshot files? Can I delete them?

There are several other big folders that I don't know what they do but these are the big ones.

It's super frustrating that I've run out of space and my app has only used 2 of the 10GB. Any advice on what I can do to clean all this up would be much appreciated!

Comment: the title states that  8GB is taken by google-cloud-sdk ... yet your output shows only 2.7GB is taken by google-cloud-sdk - anyway, those aren't "snapshots" they are Canonical Snaps - i.e. stuff installed using `snap` I guess

Answer (score 0):

> Are these snapshot files? Can I delete them?

They are [snap packages](https://ubuntu.com/core/services/guide/snaps-intro). You can remove them if you want. [`man snap`](https://manpages.org/snap) will tell you how to interact with them.

`snap remove <packagename>` will uninstall it.

Furthermore, they take up less space than seen by `du`, as the content is stored in a compressed filesystem image in `/var/lib/snapd`. `/snap` is the mountpoint of the compressed filesystem.